# change outputText to inputText in primesface showcases

Tags: primefaces, commandbutton

In the showcase 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf

When the user click the edit button on row, we call

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" />
```

to set the selectedCar and after that `update=":form:display"` will update the data of `h:outputText` in dialog and shown.

But when I change the `<h:outputText>` to `<h:inputText>` the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` does not work anymore, so it raise the exception.
Here is the code and exception:
    datatableRowSelection.xhtml

```
 <h:form id="form">  

        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />  

        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.carsSmall}">  

        <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.year}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">  
            <h:outputText value="#{car.color}" />  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column style="width:4%">  
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update=":form:display" oncomplete="carDialog.show()" icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{car}" target="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" />  
            </p:commandButton>  
        </p:column>  

    </p:dataTable>  

    <p:dialog header="Car Detail" widgetVar="carDialog" resizable="false" id="carDlg"  
                showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode" modal="true">  

        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4" style="margin:0 auto;">  

            <f:facet name="header">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cars/#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}.jpg"/>  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="Model:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  

            <h:outputText value="Year:" />  
            <h:outputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.year}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  


            <h:outputText value="Manufacturer:" />  
            <h:inputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.manufacturer}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  <!-- I changed outputText to inputText here -->

            <h:outputText value="Color:" />  
            <h:inputText value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.color}" style="font-weight:bold"/>  <!-- I changed outputText to inputText here -->

        </h:panelGrid>  

    </p:dialog>  

</h:form>
```

TableBean.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.UUID;  

import org.primefaces.examples.domain.Car;  

public class TableBean {  

    static {  
        colors = new String[10];  
        colors[0] = "Black";  
        colors[1] = "White";  
        colors[2] = "Green";  
        colors[3] = "Red";  
        colors[4] = "Blue";  
        colors[5] = "Orange";  
        colors[6] = "Silver";  
        colors[7] = "Yellow";  
        colors[8] = "Brown";  
        colors[9] = "Maroon";  

        manufacturers = new String[10];  
        manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";  
        manufacturers[1] = "BMW";  
        manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";  
        manufacturers[3] = "Audi";  
        manufacturers[4] = "Renault";  
        manufacturers[5] = "Opel";  
        manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";  
        manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";  
        manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";  
        manufacturers[9] = "Ford";  
    }  

    private final static String[] colors;  

    private final static String[] manufacturers;  

    private List<Car> cars;  

    private Car selectedCar;  

    public TableBean() {  
        cars = new ArrayList<Car>();  

        populateRandomCars(cars, 50);  
    }  

    private void populateRandomCars(List<Car> list, int size) {  
        for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)  
            list.add(new Car(getRandomModel(), getRandomYear(), getRandomManufacturer(), getRandomColor()));  
    }  

    public Car getSelectedCar() {  
        return selectedCar;  
    }  
    public void setSelectedCar(Car selectedCar) {  
        this.selectedCar = selectedCar;  
    }  

    public List<Car> getCars() {  
        return cars;  
    }  

    private int getRandomYear() {  
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1960);  
    }  

    private String getRandomColor() {  
        return colors[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  

    private String getRandomManufacturer() {  
        return manufacturers[(int) (Math.random() * 10)];  
    }  

    private String getRandomModel() {  
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0, 8);  
    }  
}
```

And the Exception is:

```
WARNING:     datatableRowSelection.xhtml value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedCar' returned null
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: datatableRowSelection.xhtml value="#{tableBean.selectedCar.model}": Target Unreachable, 'selectedCar' returned null
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1034)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:964)
at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1237)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:702)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1220)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1612)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1623)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:253)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1162)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could you please tell me why?
Thanks so much

Comment: You should provide more code from bean.

Comment: <h:inputText> need getter and setter, and i think your 'model' properties in 'selectedCar' type doesn't have setter.

Comment: 'selectedCar returned null', you may need to initialize selectedCar because you change outputtext to inputtext.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do the same as in the Primefaces showcase link on the question, just added the setter to the bean and change the <h:outputText> to <h:inputText>. About the null I think we no need to set because when we click the button, it use p:setPropertyActionListener to set data and after that update fields in dialog.

Comment: Where is the code? Unless you want to keep well-meaning users on here guessing, please post code

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I added the code with the part code modified. Hope it easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, because the dialog in the same form with the table. After I split it to 2 form, it works well. Could you please explain me why?

Comment: hello this comment save my day.... Thanks!!!! i had the same issue.... did u find the explanation?? is an issue very strange... :S